Combi bar plot and line plot for multi-column data in ggplot
For data as bellow
Year <- c(2014, 2015, 2016)
one <- c(1000, 1100, 1200)
two <- c(800, 900, 1100)
three <- c(200,200,100)

df <- data.frame(one,two,three)

I want to plot in ggplot as bellow

I have code for plot one bar and line (as bellow)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Year, y = one), stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = two), stat = "identity")


This question is the same except for the single rather than side-by-side bars.

The replicates the image you posted. Note that I've changed the data a bit to make that possible.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Year <- c(2014, 2015, 2016)
One <- c(1000, 900, 200)
Two <- c(1100, 800, 100)
#Three <- c(200,200,100)
Three <- c(1200,1100,100)


df <- data.frame(Year, One, Two, Three) %>% 
  # x is the value to map ontop the x-axis
  mutate(x = row_number())

# transform the data into long format, so that we can use podition_dodge()
df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(x), 
    names_to = "variable", 
    values_to = "value"
    ) %>%
  # make sure the order of the levels is correct
  mutate(
    variable = factor(
      variable, 
      levels = c("Year", "One", "Two", "Three")
      )
    ) 

# color palette to use with scale_fill* and scale_color*
palette = c(
  Year = "#146082", One = "#e97231", 
  Two = "#1a6b25", Three = "#0d9ed5"
  )

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = value)) + 
  geom_col(
    # filter the data for this geom to exclude "Three"
    data = filter(df, variable != "Three"),
    aes(x = x, y = value, fill = variable), 
    # place Year, One and Two side-by-side
    position = position_dodge()
    )+ 
  # add the line for "Three"
  geom_line(
    data = filter(df, variable == "Three"), 
    aes(
      # scale the y-values to match the scale of the bars
      y = value * 2500/1400, 
      color = variable), 
    lwd = 2
    ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = palette) +
  scale_color_manual(values = palette) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 2500, 500),
    limits = c(0, 2500),
    name = NULL,
    # the secondary axis is used to display the values of "Three"
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1400/2500,
                        name = "",
                        breaks = seq(0, 1400, 200))
    )+
  guides(
    # hide leged titles
    fill = guide_legend(title = NULL),
    color = guide_legend(title = NULL))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1,
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    # make the keys in the legend wider
    legend.key.width = unit(36, "pt"),
    legend.key.height = unit(12, "pt"),
    # increase spacing between the keys
    legend.key.spacing.y = unit(2, "pt"),
    # decrease spacing between the filL and color keys
    legend.spacing.y = unit(-10, "pt"),
)

